# Unity Adressables Android Unable to load dependent bundle from location

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Adressables 1.7.5, Unity 2019.2.14f1

I'm using such workflow. I'm using cdn, preloading all bundles on game start. All ok both Editor(Use existing build play mode script) and Android. I use GetDownloadSizeAsync and if its result > 0, i use DownloadDependenciesAsync, both IList. All debugs shows ok, with size, percent(small bug with last percent log as 48%). After all in Editor it works perfect with both LoadAssetAsync with key or reference. Tryed with no interner. So it was downloaded and cached. But on android i always get GetDownloadSizeAsync > 0 and after it on LoadAssetAsync(both key and reference) i get Unable to load dependent bundle from location.

And now i noticed that it downloads every time game started. So GetDownloadSizeAsync is always > 0 on device. All download logs says all ok.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with last 2019.3 Unity. Works as expected.